# Durbin-Watson test for first order autocorrelation when interaction effects are present

Tags: econometrics, autocorrelation

I have a multiple linear regression model (OLS) that has a constant, 5 variables, and an interaction term between two of the dummy variables.

I need to perform the Durbin-Watson test for first-order correlation, and in order to find the critical values, I need to know the number of explanatory variables (not taking into account the constant).

Is the interaction term an explanatory variable in itself for these purposes (so I have 6 explanatory vars), or do I find the critical values for 5 explanatory vars?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interaction counts as an explanatory variable. If there is a factor involved in the interaction, all of the levels after the first count (so an interaction between two factors can count as many terms in this situation).